# Can't perform upgrade due to failing util-linux, insserv & initscripts

Tags: 16.04, apt, dpkg, init.d

Routine upgrade of 16.04.6 server has been failing with following errors:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.8) ...
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01php7.0-fpm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01urandom
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01php7.2-fpm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01lxcfs
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K10cryptdisks-early
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01unattended-upgrades
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01lsyncd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01open-iscsi
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K13halt
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01fail2ban
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K05umountnfs.sh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01nginx
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01uuidd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01lxd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01mysql
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01elasticsearch
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01apache2
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01plymouth
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K12mdadm-waitidle
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K09cryptdisks
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01lvm2-lvmpolld
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K07networking
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01redis-server
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K11umountroot
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K08umountfs
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01apache-htcacheclean
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01mdadm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01incron
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K06rpcbind
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01resolvconf
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01open-vm-tools
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01atd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K02iscsid
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K04rsyslog
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01irqbalance
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K03sendsigs
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01lvm2-lvmetad
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01php7.0-fpm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K02ufw
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01php7.2-fpm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01lxcfs
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/S01killprocs
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01lsyncd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01open-iscsi
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01fail2ban
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01nginx
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01uuidd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01lxd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/S02single
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01mysql
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01elasticsearch
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01apache2
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01lvm2-lvmpolld
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01redis-server
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01apache-htcacheclean
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01mdadm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01incron
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K06rpcbind
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01open-vm-tools
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01atd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K02iscsid
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K04rsyslog
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01irqbalance
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01lvm2-lvmetad
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S01apport
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S04ondemand
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S03redis-server
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S01php7.0-fpm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S01open-vm-tools
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S03fail2ban
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S01lvm2-lvmetad
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/K01lsyncd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S02apache2
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S04plymouth
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S03nginx
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S03cron
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S01uuidd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S03irqbalance
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S03rsync
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S03atd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S01unattended-upgrades
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S01elasticsearch
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S03dbus
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S03mdadm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S03acpid
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S03ssh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S03mysql
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S01rsyslog
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S01lvm2-lvmpolld
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S04grub-common
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S04rc.local
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/K01apache-htcacheclean
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S01php7.2-fpm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S01lxcfs
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S03incron
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S01lxd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S01apport
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S04ondemand
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S03redis-server
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S01php7.0-fpm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S01open-vm-tools
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S03fail2ban
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S01lvm2-lvmetad
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/K01lsyncd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S02apache2
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S04plymouth
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S03nginx
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S03cron
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S01uuidd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S03irqbalance
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S03rsync
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S03atd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S01unattended-upgrades
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S01elasticsearch
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S03dbus
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S03mdadm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S03acpid
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S03ssh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S03mysql
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S01rsyslog
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S01lvm2-lvmpolld
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S04grub-common
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S04rc.local
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/K01apache-htcacheclean
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S01php7.2-fpm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S01lxcfs
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S03incron
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S01lxd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S01apport
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S04ondemand
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S03redis-server
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S01php7.0-fpm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S01open-vm-tools
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S03fail2ban
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S01lvm2-lvmetad
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/K01lsyncd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S02apache2
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S04plymouth
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S03nginx
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S03cron
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S01uuidd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S03irqbalance
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S03rsync
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S03atd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S01unattended-upgrades
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S01elasticsearch
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S03dbus
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S03mdadm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S03acpid
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S03ssh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S03mysql
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S01rsyslog
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S01lvm2-lvmpolld
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S04grub-common
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S04rc.local
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/K01apache-htcacheclean
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S01php7.2-fpm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S01lxcfs
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S03incron
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S01lxd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S01apport
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S04ondemand
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S03redis-server
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S01php7.0-fpm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S01open-vm-tools
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S03fail2ban
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S01lvm2-lvmetad
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/K01lsyncd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S02apache2
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S04plymouth
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S03nginx
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S03cron
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S01uuidd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S03irqbalance
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S03rsync
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S03atd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S01unattended-upgrades
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S01elasticsearch
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S03dbus
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S03mdadm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S03acpid
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S03ssh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S03mysql
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S01rsyslog
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S01lvm2-lvmpolld
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S04grub-common
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S04rc.local
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/K01apache-htcacheclean
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S01php7.2-fpm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S01lxcfs
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S03incron
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S01lxd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01php7.0-fpm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01urandom
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01php7.2-fpm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01lxcfs
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K13reboot
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K10cryptdisks-early
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01unattended-upgrades
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01lsyncd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01open-iscsi
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01fail2ban
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K05umountnfs.sh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01nginx
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01uuidd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01lxd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01mysql
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01elasticsearch
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01apache2
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01plymouth
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K12mdadm-waitidle
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K09cryptdisks
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01lvm2-lvmpolld
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K07networking
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01redis-server
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K11umountroot
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K08umountfs
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01apache-htcacheclean
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01mdadm
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01incron
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K06rpcbind
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01resolvconf
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01open-vm-tools
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01atd
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K02iscsid
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K04rsyslog
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01irqbalance
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K03sendsigs
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01lvm2-lvmetad
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S02screen-cleanup
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S02ufw
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S01console-setup
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S08lvm2
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S13open-iscsi
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S02apparmor
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S11mountall.sh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S11networking
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S02plymouth-log
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S02resolvconf
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S13mountnfs.sh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S12iscsid
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S06checkroot.sh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S07cryptdisks-early
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S10checkfs.sh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S02hostname.sh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S02x11-common
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S15bootmisc.sh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S09cryptdisks
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S08urandom
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S08kmod
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S14mountnfs-bootclean.sh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S12mountall-bootclean.sh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S04procps
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S02mountkernfs.sh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S04mountdevsubfs.sh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S03udev
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S08checkroot-bootclean.sh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S12rpcbind
insserv: Service mountdevsubfs has to be enabled to start service hwclock
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd:
 systemd depends on util-linux (>= 2.27.1); however:
  Package util-linux is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So, packages involved are util-linux, insserv and initscripts, but StackOverflow won't allow me tag them for some dumb reason. Whatever.

So far I've tried:

- invoking `apt update --fix-missing`;
- manually installing `util-linux`, `insserv` & `initscripts` (same error);
- `apt -f install`;
- `dpkg-reconfigure`;
- `dpkg –-configure --a`;

And yet, none has worked. By opening a random script, like `/etc/rc6.d/K09crypdisks`, I see that it's perfectly valid, so I suspect something in installer logic is broken and I need to somehow purge and reinstall this unholy trinity of packages manually, without downing the server. Or stubbing related checks, but that's gonna cause integrity problem, so I'd rather avoid it. I also had an error regarding `/etc/alternatives/page`r providing incorrect link, but I've fixed it with `update-alternatives`. I'm mentioning this just in case it makes any relevance.

Comment: Do you have a legacy init system running? what is the output of `ps -q 1 -o comm=`

Comment: systemd. 16.04 has switched to it by default.

Answer (score 1):

From [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1613970/comments/7)

First run:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/util-linux.postinst
```

and then run:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f
```

---

### Edit 2

Source: [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1613970/comments/3)
From the same thread, we also have:

```
sudo dpkg --purge usplash
sudo dpkg --purge readahead
sudo dpkg --configure initscripts
sudo dpkg --configure util-linux
```

Getting rid of stale initscripts from usplash and readahead removed a couple of init script dependency loops, which let dpkg --configure util-linux proceed.

`sudo apt dist-upgrade -f` is running now.

Comment: That didn't do it: [SO won't allow to post the rest of the errors]
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S08checkroot-bootclean.sh
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rcS.d/S12rpcbind
invoke-rc.d: not a symlink: /etc/rc5.d/S04grub-common
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 102
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/grub-common_2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.22_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @ivdok You can use a service like https://paste.ubuntu.com to paste the whole output and share the link here.